# Bash BTC and LTC address generator

Tags: address, vanity-address, vanitygen

Do you know any bash script or C simple program to generate btc and ltc addresses? I need to generate address while in recovery mode on osx or on a linux onthefly. But I cannot find such a thing on github: they're in python or never compiles or just do btc or ltc.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this with [CryptoCoinJS](http://cryptocoinjs.com/).

First [download Node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/). Then do the following:

Make a new directory:

```
mkdir /tmp/myapp
cd /tmp/myapp
```

Initialize your app:

```
npm init
```

Then run:

```
npm install --save coinkey@1.1.0
```

Then run:

```
npm install --save coininfo@0.2.0
```

Create your js file:

```
touch app.js
```

Put the following:

```
var CoinKey = require('coinkey')
var ci = require('coininfo')

var amount = 10
//generate a bunch of Litecoin addresses
for (var i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
  var ck = CoinKey.createRandom(ci('LTC').versions) //change LTC to BTC if you want Bitcoin
  console.log(ck.privateWif + ': ' + ck.publicAddress)
}
```

Run your script:

```
node app.js
```

Documentation for [coinkey](http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/currency/coinkey/)
Documentation for [coininfo](http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/currency/coininfo/).

Hope this helps. If something doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: ehi jp, I'll try and give a feed! thanks!